# Unable to install my add on from G Suite Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-addons) procedure to publish my add-on on the Chrome Web Store as well as G Suite Market Place. The respective links are below.

- [CWS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/met-script-3/iabaaadkdhmiohnaecichknjbgngnmko?authuser=0)
- [GSMP](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/met_script_3/919196343231)

Problem is that I can install it from CWS but when I try GSMP it doesn't work.

Could the visibility option in CWS cause such an issue? For this particular listing it is set to `Unlisted` which means only people with the link can find it.

Comment: Your question is off topic to Stack Overflow.  There is a group for Google Add-ons [link To Developing add-ons for G Suite](https://plus.google.com/communities/117193953428311185494)

Comment: @SandyGood Its relevance is mentioned under **Questions and Advice** section [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/support#questions_and_advice)

Comment: The link that you provided is to Google documentation.  Google doesn't run Stack Overflow or set the rules for Stack Overflow.  That Google documentation is not the official policy set at Stack Overflow.  It's very common for people to think that Stack Overflow is somehow an official support resource for Google products.  Google gets free promotion and support through Stack Overflow.  But ultimately, even the Stack Overflow rules are totally meaningless unless Stack Overflow does something to enforce the rules.  And Stack Overflow wants more new members.

Comment: It can be inferred from the provided link that people at Google think posting such questions on Stack Overflow is relevant. So are you saying that they are wrong?

Comment: If the add-on is unlisted the only way to get to it is with a direct link. Yours is available at https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/met_script_3/919196343231